# WebView2, bind to local address, C++

Tags: webview2

I want to bind [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/?view=webview2-0.8.355) to local address. (LAN adapter)
Is it possible to do this?

There are multiple network adapters on the same computer. I want the WebView2 browser to use an adapter chosen from the code and I want it to access the internet through the same adapter.

```
WebView2.Bind("192.168.1.10"); // ???
WebView2.Navigate("www.google.com");
```

It seems it can be done by defining a proxy, but it will be necessary to check the specified proxy server from within the code.

```
auto options = Microsoft::WRL::Make<CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions>();
options->put_AdditionalBrowserArguments(L"--proxy-server=\"192.168.1.125\"");
```

From what I understand from the answers, WebView2 doesn't seem to have such capability.

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: I also may not understand what you mean by "bind WebView2 to local address", can you elaborate? WebView2 has no way to configure which adapter is used. WebView2 uses the same networking code as the Edge browser. If you have a web server running on the same machine you can navigate to http://localhost:8080/ or whatever the address is to your local web server without needing to bind to a particular network.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: WebView2 spans a variety of use cases, are you trying to use localhost in WebView2 for WPF, you may need to give more details. please see the URL https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/291 it may be useful

Comment: There are multiple network adapters on the same computer. I want the WebView2 browser to use an adapter chosen from within the code.

Comment: WebView2 doesn't have a way to pick a network adapter.

Comment: Thanks David Risney.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it was a little challenging, I was able to fix my issue by using a web proxy server.

I used the [Titanium Web Proxy](https://github.com/justcoding121/titanium-web-proxy) library.

I set the proxy settings of WebView2 in C++ to the exe that was made using the Titanium Web Proxy library in C#.

```cpp
ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T(".\TitaniumWebProxy.exe"), _T("192.168.1.10:8000"), NULL, SW_HIDE);
auto options = Microsoft::WRL::Make<CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions>();
options->put_AdditionalBrowserArguments(L"--proxy-server=\"192.168.1.10:8000\"");
```

Thanks to everyone who took the time to reply.